# split a column into multiple rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to move one columns data into rows and split it to 24 columns. For better understanding, I already put the sample of my dataset below. Here is my dataset, basically I wanna divide my 'bb' column to 24 columns, where rest of the columns will have the same information as before. Thus, from cc columns will split into 24 columns from one. And it will be repeated till the end. Here is my data:

```
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj, kk, ll, mm, nn
1   1  0.1 0.3 94  60  5   1  -2.  29  25  12  28  0
.
.
1   24  0.1 0.3 94  60  5   1  -2.  29  25  12  28  0
```

I already split the bb columns into the row. My code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',')

flg = 0
'''Select the features for moving one column to 24 hours columns '''
for j in range(3, 14):
'''Taking data 0 to 23'''
   for i in range(24):
        ''' select all the features in the hour column where hour value is i '''
        index_for_ith_hour_feature = np.where(dataframe.iloc[:, 1] == i)[0]
        '''if the flag value 1 it will enter the loop for making one column to 24 hour columns'''
        if flg == 1:
            '''taking all the data where jth value will be constant and 24 hours features will be selected and stacked horizontally'''
            buffer = dataframe.iloc[index_for_ith_hour_feature, j].values.reshape(-1, 1)
            '''stack all the data with buffer'''
            all_data = np.hstack((all_data, buffer))
        else:
            '''first loop will comes here because flg=0, after that, it will go to if loop and continue'''
            all_data = dataframe.iloc[index_for_ith_hour_feature, j].values.reshape(-1, 1)
            flg = 1

'''Select date columns'''
date_data_column = dataframe.iloc[index_for_ith_hour_feature, 0:2].values

'''stacking date columns and all the features previously selected'''
all_data = np.hstack((date_data_column, all_data))
print(all_data)
```

But It seems I have done some mistake in my code. I don't understand from where the problem is coming from. It's not showing any output till now. It will be really helpful for me to figure it out the mistake from here or better way to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand what output you want. Seems like either you need to `.get_dummies` or `.pivot_table`, so can you provide your expected output to see exactly which one it is?

Comment: I agree, an example of your desired output would help. From my reading of the question, it sounds like you just want to make the rows columns ans the columns rows, which is just transposing, or `df.T`

Comment: My output will be like: aa, bb, cc_01,...cc24, dd_01,.., dd_24,........nn_01,... nn_24 It means except first two columns all the features will have 24 columns where values will be the same as my raw data. In details, I want my 24 hours(bb) data columns as a row for each features.